# How to bind a mouse to a key in AHK language?

Tags: key, bind

I am new to ahk. I know how to bind a key to a key (a::b), but is it possible to bind a key to a mouse click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on key you want to bind. You can use

```
a::Click    ; for most of the keys
`;::Click   ; escaping special characters such as ";" is required
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways. For example:

```
g::click
```

or

```
h::mouseclick
```

If you want to do additional stuff when mouse is pressed down you can do this

```
d::
Click down  
MsgBox You pressed down d.
KeyWait, d 
Click up
MsgBox You released d.
return
```